# 3D Flood Fill Algorithm on a 3D Array (Java)

Tags: arrays, 3d

I have searched the forums extensively and nothing quite covers this. I am looking to do what I'd call essentially a 3D Flood Fill algorithm on an array on enum types. Rather than changing the "color" of the array elements, I'd like to change the enum type in it. This is what I have so far, could you guys let me know if you think this will work or if you have any suggestions?

```
 /*
  * CellType is my enum type. BOUNDRY_BOX enum type is type that I line the whole 3D array with. So the
  * whole inside surface of the 3D box is filled with CellType.BOUNDRY_BOX.
  **/
 public void fillAllVoidCells(CellType[][][] grid, CellType targetType, CellType replacementType, int x, int y, int z)
 {
    if ((grid[x][y][z] != targetType) && grid[x][y][z] != CellType.BOUNDRY_BOX)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        grid[x][y][z] = replacementType;

        fillAllVoidCells(grid, targetType, replacementType, x + 1, y, z);   // right
        fillAllVoidCells(grid, targetType, replacementType, x - 1, y, z);   // left
        fillAllVoidCells(grid, targetType, replacementType, x, y + 1, z);   // in front
        fillAllVoidCells(grid, targetType, replacementType, x, y - 1, z);   // behind
        fillAllVoidCells(grid, targetType, replacementType, x, y, z + 1);   // above
        fillAllVoidCells(grid, targetType, replacementType, x, y, z - 1);   // below
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

- break does not mean what you think it does. You should use return to leave the function
- You may want to check whether you are at the boundary of your domain before calling the function for the adjacent cells (otherwise, it will crash)
- using a recursion for a flood fill is great... for educational purpose only. Using a queue is much more efficient
- a simple thing is to try it out and see whether it works !

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was very useful. I have made much progress, could you please refer to here for a followup question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294856/using-recursion-for-3d-array-manipulation-causing-stackoverflow-not-infinite