# Using Recursion for 3D Array Manipulation -- Causing StackOverflow (not Infinite!)

Tags: recursion, stack, queue

I recently posted a question yesterday about a similar issue, but I have coded up something a little different and now have a different problem. Here is my code that is causing a StackOverflow.

** Note that the 3D grid array is upwards of 1 million elements and can reach up to around 64 million elements (stores enums).

** Also note that this is not going into infinity. On small data sets, this algorithm works fine.

Is this likely caused by the extreme recursion? How do I handle this (this is an essential part of my algorithm!)? I've done some research and have heard using a queue, for even just massive for-loops.

What will reduce the likelihood of causing a stackoverflow?

Thank you!

```
/**
 * Fills all void cells in the 3D grid of Atom.
 *
 * @param x
 *            The starting x coordinate
 * @param y
 *            The starting y coordinate
 * @param z
 *            The starting z coordinate
 */
private void fillAllVoidCells(int x, int y, int z)
{
    // Base case -- If not BLOATED_ATOM, BOUNDING_BOX,
    // or VOID then must be a cavity (only 4 CellType
    // enum types.
    if ((grid[x][y][z] == CellType.BLOATED_ATOM)
        || grid[x][y][z] == CellType.BOUNDING_BOX
        || grid[x][y][z] == CellType.VOID)
    {
        // Pop off runtime stack
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Set to void then check all surrounding cells.
        grid[x][y][z] = CellType.VOID;

        fillAllVoidCells(x + 1, y, z); // right
        fillAllVoidCells(x - 1, y, z); // left
        fillAllVoidCells(x, y + 1, z); // in front
        fillAllVoidCells(x, y - 1, z); // behind
        fillAllVoidCells(x, y, z + 1); // above
        fillAllVoidCells(x, y, z - 1); // below
    }
}
```

===== EDIT ====== New Method Implemented Using a Stack (per Roee Gavirel help)
Would this be a correct implementation?

```
   // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Fills all void cells in the 3D grid of Atom.
     *
     * @param x
     *            The starting x coordinate
     * @param y
     *            The starting y coordinate
     * @param z
     *            The starting z coordinate
     */
    private void fillAllVoidCells(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        Point p = new Point(x, y, z);

        stack.push(p);

        while (!stack.isEmpty())
            p = stack.top();
        stack.pop();

        // Base case -- If not BLOATED_ATOM, BOUNDING_BOX,
        // or VOID then must be a cavity (only 4 CellType
        // enum types.
        CellType state = grid[p.x][p.y][p.z];

        if ((state == CellType.BLOATED_ATOM) || state == CellType.BOUNDING_BOX
            || state == CellType.VOID)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set to void then check all surrounding cells.
            grid[p.x][p.y][p.z] = CellType.VOID;
            Point tempP = p;

            tempP.x = p.x - 1;
            stack.push(tempP);
            tempP.x = p.x + 1;
            stack.push(tempP);
            tempP.x = p.x; // return to original x coordinate

            tempP.y = p.y - 1;
            stack.push(tempP);
            tempP.y = p.y + 1;
            stack.push(tempP);
            tempP.y = p.y; // return to original y coordiante

            tempP.z = p.z - 1;
            stack.push(tempP);
            tempP.z = p.z + 1;
            stack.push(tempP);
            tempP.z = p.z; // return to original z coordinate
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely to cause an overflow. what you can (and should) do to avoid it is to use your own stack for the data and avoid recursion.

In you case:
1. have a stack of relevant points (x,y,z) which have the point you initially called `fillAllVoidCells` with.
2. `while` the stack is not empty you should do your checks
3. If it's `cavity` add the surrounding points to the stack.

==EDIT== 
something like that:

```
struct point {
    int x,y,z;
}

private void fillAllVoidCells(int x, int y, int z)
{
    std::list<point> Ps;
    point p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    p.z = z;
    Ps.push_back(p);

    while (!Ps.empty())
        p = Ps.back();
        Ps.pop_back();

        // Base case -- If not BLOATED_ATOM, BOUNDING_BOX,
        // or VOID then must be a cavity (only 4 CellType
        // enum types.
        auto state = grid[p.x][p.y][p.z];
        if ((state == CellType.BLOATED_ATOM)
            || state == CellType.BOUNDING_BOX
            || state == CellType.VOID)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set to void then check all surrounding cells.
            grid[p.x][p.y][p.z] = CellType.VOID;

            point tempP = p;
            tempP.x = P.x - 1;    
            Ps.push_back(tempP);
            tempP.x = P.x + 1;    
            Ps.push_back(tempP);
            tempP.y = P.y - 1;    
            Ps.push_back(tempP);
            tempP.y = P.y + 1;    
            Ps.push_back(tempP);
            tempP.z = P.z - 1;    
            Ps.push_back(tempP);
            tempP.z = P.z + 1;    
            Ps.push_back(tempP);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am a little confused. So I should have a stack that stores the array elements, but the important part is that the location in the 3D array matters to the rest of my program. I am trying to model a 3D protein and need the appropriate x, y, z coordinates (represented by grid[x][y][z]). How would I handle this?

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo I add a code (not tested) that will give you the direction you should take.

Comment: Great thank you very much! I am going to try to implement this in Java tonight. What is the likelyhood of this causing a StackOverflow or OutOfMemory Exception? (array has > 1,000,000 elemeents)

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo this want cause stack overflow since your element are not been saved on the stack. regarding OutOfMemory unless you have 4Mb RAM I don't think so (:

Comment: Thank you so much again for you help. I added an implementation in Java that I believe will work. Could you check this over? The one thing I believe you may have missed (correct me if im wrong!) is  that after I adjust the x coodinate (or y or z) by plus 1 or minus 1 and push both of them onto the stack, I set tempP's x back to the original x coordinate. Is this correct (see commented code above)?

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly the logic of the code (I've not had data structures yet). Should the while loop encompass the whole method basically (including all the pushes on the stack)? Currently the code I posted does not encompass all of that.